# How to make Application Menu icon small again?

Tags: 18.04, kde

My Application Menu icon turned great

[image]

How to make it small again?

Comment: You should check this resource: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8rj760/how_can_i_change_the_size_of_the_kde_application/